# How to run a command after a process was started by another process started by a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Does anybody know how to create a batch for starting an application, then setting process priority of another application to a lower priority than normal, next waiting until one more process is started, and finally setting process priority of this last started process to a higher priority than normal?

I would appreciate it if you would help me because this is for my business (Internet Cafe).

So I need the batch file to start **Valorant** (technically the Riot client on **Valorant** config). Then set **Chrome** process to low process priority after user logged in and sets **Valorant** (technically `VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe`) to high process priority.

Here are the commands required for the task.

The command that runs **Valorant** (Riot login client) on cmd.

```
"C:\Riot Games\Riot Client\RiotClientServices.exe" --launch-product=valorant --launch-patchline=live
```

The command that sets **Chrome** to low priority (and stops **Chrome** from taking whole CPU resources of my PC.)

```
wmic process where name="chrome.exe" call setpriority "64"
```

The command that sets **Valorant** (the game process) to high priority.

```
wmic process where name="VALORANT-Win64-Shipping" call setpriority "128"
```

Further please note this: After the login client started, the game process doesn't start right away. There must be code added that waits for the game process to start after executing the first command which is basically my problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A commented batch file for this task could be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Start Riot client as parallel running separate process.
start "" /D"C:\Riot Games\Riot Client" "C:\Riot Games\Riot Client\RiotClientServices.exe" --launch-product=valorant --launch-patchline=live

rem Define 120 seconds as maximum time for waiting for game process.
set RetryCount=120

rem In a loop wait one second, then look up in task list if the game process
rem is already running. If game process is running, exit the loop and change
rem the process priorities. Otherwise decrement the retry counter and exit
rem the loop on reaching value zero with informing the batch file user that
rem game process was not started within two minutes.

:WaitLoop
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe" /NH 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /C /I "VALORANT-Win64-Shipping" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto GameStarted
set /A RetryCount-=1
if not %RetryCount% == 0 goto WaitLoop

echo Valorant game was not started within two minutes.
echo(
pause
goto EndBatch

:GameStarted
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PROCESS where name="chrome.exe" CALL SetPriority 64 >nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PROCESS where name="VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe" CALL SetPriority 128 >nul

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`
- `tasklist /?`
- `timeout /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic process /?`
- `wmic process call /?`
- `wmic process call setpriority /?`

See also:

- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)
- Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul` and `2>nul` and `|`.